# Can the dataset designer in Visual Studio 2008 show the data types for data tables columns?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Can  the dataset designer in Visual Studio 2008 show the data types for data tables columns?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. In the design view of the xsd file, click on the TableAdapter, then click on the individual column and launch the Properties window. You should be able to view the properties of the column including its data type (assuming that the columns in the TableAdapter are mapped to the DataTable, by default they are, but if you have changed them then they wont be mapped).

Comment: I don't have a datatable. the xsd is created in the designer. There are no database tables.